# mercurial workflow with multiple non-live environments

Tags: mercurial, workflow

I work on a project where we have Live, RC, and QA. Individual issues go to QA when they're ready where the QA team tests the ticket's functionality. Once the ticket passes, it's ready to move to RC. Before a release we take all of the issues that are ready and put them all on RC together where we make sure that tickets don't cause problems with each other. Once that's done all of RC moves to live together.

What is a good way to handle this with Mercurial? Our current process has some problems.

### Our current process:

Live runs default, RC runs a branch created off of default (live) and QA runs it's own branch (trunk) that branched from default in the past.

Issues are branched from default, worked, and then merged to trunk. Once a ticket is ready to go to RC it gets merged into the upcoming release branch. When that gets tested the release branch gets merged into default and default gets merged back into trunk. The problem we're running into is that after a while something happens and everything gets conflicts merging to trunk. If we resolve conflicts to trunk in that merge it tends to break trunk much faster, if we have conflicts we merge default into our branch and resolve them in that commit. This usually works but after a few weeks or months trunk seems to break and we can no longer resolve the conflicts.

### Update:

Our process works such that ticket A might move into the QA environment and stay there for a while. Ticket B might be developed, moved to QA, QAed and on RC and released before ticket A ever leaves the QA environment. That is not something that can be changed right now. I'm looking for a solution that fits our needs. I have the ability to influence our implementation of the process at the repository level, but not the ability to modify the over all process in a significant way right now.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet  is reviewing Mercurial's suggested [workflows](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Workflows).  I can tell you from my own experience with a structured release cycle that had code (features, enhancements, and bug fixes) going to a QA environment for verification and prepping releases, then branching from those release tags for emergency patches, Mercurial fits nicely.

For my steps below, "trunk" is just what others might call mainline.  There isn't any term "trunk" in Mercurial.  You just have the repository you are working from, which is either just your local repository or a clone of another repository (still local).

1. trunk is where everyone generally works.
2. When a particular change is completed, it is pushed to a central server (still trunk and a central server is optional, just makes the workflow easier with continuous integration).
3. From the central server repository, a build is done and pushed to the QA server.
4. QA tests the functionality and should also generally test limited interaction outside the known change.
5. If change passes QA testing, a release manager may choose to tag that changeset as the version number to be released (`hg tag "name of tag"`).
6. Once code is tagged and ready for a release, another build can be done to push to a user acceptance test environment (UAT), which mimics production configuration.
7. If UAT passes, a final build can be done to push into production.  Note that you can save some build steps by using separate "build" repositories that hold only pre-built copies of your software.  That way, only a single build needs to be done if QA and UAT testing passes before pushing to production.
8. If a defect is found in the production release, a branch can be created from the tagged revision that was released (say 1.0.0) using `hg update "tag name"` then `hg branch "name of branch"` (which should probably match the tag name).
9. While "on" the branch revision, fix the bug, commit, merge it to "trunk".
10. Do a build from the latest revision "on" the branch and push that to QA.
11. If testing is successful, that build can be moved to UAT and production as necessary and you can feel confident that you are only releasing that single bug fix.

All the while, new functionality, features, and non-critical bug fixes can be done in "trunk", continuing with the "next" version of the code to be released on a schedule.